# Access Popup Source code - Python requests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website.

Adress: https://park4night.com/carte_lieux?lat=41.25807499996962&lng=9.426118999656891&zoom=38

I would like to get the link in the popup appearing when clicking on the pin-point. But I'm having trouble getting the source code to scrape. Using request the source code of the website does not include the one appearing when clicking the marker.

Pin: [image: pin to click to access popup]

Popup link is the redirecting link by clicking "Voir le lieu": [image]

Xpath link I would like to access: `/html/body/div[5]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a`

By running `$x('/html/body/div[5]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/@href')[0]`
in the javascript console I'm able to get the desired link. I don't know how to perform the same action in python.

How can I access that information? Do I have to use selenium? (since I don't need to perform more actions besides of the ones already possible with requests and lxml.html)

Premise, I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff. Getting handy on handling requests, xPath, ...

Thank you!

Comment: _clicking the marker_: What is marker here?

Comment: You need to publish at least some of the code you've already tried to use so people can see where the problem you reported is. And if possible a more visual indication of what you want.

Comment: Have you LOOKED at the HTML for that page, either through "View Source" or by using "wget" or "curl"?  The map is built entirely through Javascript.  It isn't in the HTML.  You would have to use Selenium.  Have you checked to see if they have an API for that information?

Comment: Sorry guys, I've updated my post with some information, can it help?

Comment: I'm aware that the page is boult through Javascript but by using requests `response = requests.get(url)` I'm able to access the information I need, usually. till now where I'm stuck with this popup issue

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `P` then click on `Voir le lieu` then it generates the desired data along with a new url which is not dynamic. So you can follow the next example.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://park4night.com/fr/lieu/161323/parking-camping-car-jour-et-nuit/porto-massimo-strada-punta-lunga/italy/provincia-di-olbia-tempio#.YnROyNpBzIV'
req=requests.get(url)
#print(req)

soup= BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

for box in soup.select('.box_template'):
    address = box.select_one('[style="float: left;width: 85%;"] > div ').get_text(strip=True)
    print(address)
```

**Output:**

```
(07024) La Maddalena , Unnamed Road
(07024) , Unnamed Road
(07024) Case Dell'abbatoggia, 2 Via Abbatoggia
(07024) La Maddalena,4 Bassa Trinita
(07024) , 4-2 Bassa Trinita
(07024) La Maddalena,
(07024) La Maddalena,Località Giardinelli     
(07024) La Maddalena,Località Giardinelli
(07024) La Maddalena,
(07024) , Località Giardinelli
```

step-1
[The original url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQHc5.png)  drag and click on p

step-2

[After click on P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S1O1.png)

step-3

[After click on location(picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HrXK.png)
From here you will see the url that is the data container url

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful! Could you help me understand how to gain access to the link you stored in `url` since I can't find it anywhere when opening the map (link: https://park4night.com/carte_lieux?lat=41.25807499996962&lng=9.426118999656891&zoom=38) because it becomes only available when the user clicks on `p`

Comment: @ SamuLibero, I've updated, please see the screenshot above

Comment: Thanks! So in order to click on `P`I would need selenium?

Comment: I'm sorry but the idea is to do It automatically, I have 4000 pins I want to scrape... ahahahah